# What to do with old floppy drives?

Tags: floppy

I have found a floppy drive lying around. However, as all my computers are connected to the net, I won't be needing it. What would be your recommendations for it, especially if I bump into situations where I may need it to repair really old computers?

Comment: If a discussion is what you want, this is the wrong place...

Comment: I edited your question a little so that it avoids being closed.

Comment: Why on earth close this? Sheesh.

Comment: Well, the mods have the power. Oh well....

Comment: Just another idea what to do with it: http://youtu.be/dmoDLyiQYKw :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'd keep it.  Some BIOS updates are still written to be booted/loaded from a floppy.  You can get around this, of course, but it makes the process more of a hassle.  Hang on to it.

Comment: I agree - I just had a need to run the Hitachi Disk Fitness Test, which comes as an installer which creates a bootable floppy disk *only*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say toss it. Pretty much the only reason you'd need a floppy drive in anything that runs a semi modern OS is for inserting drivers into xp (and you are better off slipstreaming drivers).

I *have* a spare usb floppy drive, but i haven't used it in the 8 years or so i've had it.

The one situation where i see a floppy drive is for installing really old oses without a bootable cd.

Comment: +1 for the old OS'. Note that there are a lot of floppy linux distributions. Plus, having floppys around makes you look pretty badass.

Comment: I don’t think slipstreaming is legal without a valid OEM agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: [MS supports it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814847) - nlite/vlite et al merely make it doable for mere mortals

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The article is for updates, not drivers.

Comment: "How to slipstream hotfixes that replace pre-existing driver files" "Note The instructions in this article are intended for slipstreaming driver-related hotfixes only. Non-driver hotfixes or security hotfixes must be slipstreamed by using the instructions that are documented in the following Knowledge Base article" Feel free to back up your initial assertation with a citation